# Creating Azure VM with Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard or Enterprise

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, azure

I am looking to create an Azure VM that has Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard (or Enterprise).  It **must** be either Standard or Enterprise, as the software that needs to be installed on it will not install / function correctly.

As far as I can tell, the standard "image" that you select from in Azure will create a Windows Server 2008 R2 Datacenter image.

Is there a way to select Standard or Enterprise that doesn't involve me creating a VM locally and then uploading to Azure?

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. That's frustrating. :-(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to select Standard or Enterprise that doesn't involve
>   me creating a VM locally and then uploading to Azure?

Unfortunately, we should create a VM locally and upload to Azure.

For now, Windows server 2008 R2 Standard or Enterprise are **not** available.

Here is the available images list:
[image]

More information about Windows server available images, please refer to this [link](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps/Microsoft.WindowsServer?tab=Overview).

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation.  Once I managed to get a locally created hyper-v disk uploaded onto Azure, I was able to then create a VM based on that image.